# weird paddles on the side of a 2021 honda accord

Tags: honda, accord, steering-wheel

There are two paddles on the steering wheel of my 2021 Honda Accord Sport, one to the left and right. The left one has a "-" symbol and the right one has a "+" symbol.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Any idea what these is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up a gear (+) or down a gear (-).

Probably mentioned in the owners handbook.

Comment: Also common on Subaru models. You do need to shift from Drive to the manual mode (at least on my father's Subaru).